# Simplest Automated Analysis and Chart Generation Tool?

Tags: charts, software-rec, analysis

Are there any products that can take a CSV of info, and quickly generate commonly-asked for info? I'm wondering if there's any way easier than pulling this into Excel or Matlab and manually doing all the different analyses.

I have a CSV with info like this:

`TIMESTAMP SALEID PRODUCT PRICE`

And I'd be looking for some tool out there that would automatically create all the relevant charts for analysis such as sales/day, revenue/day, avg revenue/day, most popular product, product by day, etc.

As I mentioned, I know the individual math behind this is relatively easy and both Matlab and Excel could both pull it off, but I'm looking for an easy way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/) and [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/) are commercial applications for this, and Spotfire especially is incredibly easy to use to explore lots of visualizations side-by-side. Both have a desktop version and an online web player ([Spotfire demo gallery](http://spotfire.tibco.com/demo/default.aspx), [Tableau demo gallery](http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/gallery)). They are both highly scalable, into the millions of rows. Both are expensive, but have free trials.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), specifically, the dynamic data [features](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/queries.html)