# Free or Open Solution for Storing and Charting CSV data

Tags: windows, storage, csv, charts

I'm presently storing CSV files, combining them, opening them in open office, creating pivot tables and then generating charts from the spreadsheet.

I've looked at OOBase, but appending csv files to base is clunky for some reason.

SQLite seems like a good database solution, but I've haven't found a good charting program that connects to it with ease.

Although open office (or libreoffice) maintains the references and allows you to update the information, this process is far from efficient. There are too many steps and it seems one program should handle all of these tasks.

A better program would be more intuitive, allow you to simply add inserts into a database, and include an interface for standard charting settings.

**EDIT** 
[Simplest Automated Analysis and Chart Generation Tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/352651/simplest-automated-analysis-and-chart-generation-tool)

The above answer references **Spotfire** and **Tableau**, each of which has a free 14 and 30 day trial. Each program is nicely streamlined and designed. I'm looking for a program between this quality and LibreOffice.

**Can you recommend a better open or free desktop solution for windows?**

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/riyadparvez/csv-to-chart github project, if you are into programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau Public 7.0 
Tibco Spotfire - Free for 1 Year
qlikview
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Visualization
http://datavisualization.ch/tools/